# Deeply assign JavaScript object literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to deeply assign a value in an object. For example:

```
const errors = {}
if(errorOnSpecificField) {
  // TypeError: Cannot read property 'subSubCategory' of undefined(…)
  errors.subCategory.subSubCategory.fieldWithError = 'Error Message'
}
```

Right now, without lodash, I can do:

```
const errors = {}
if(errorOnSpecificField) {
    errors.subCategory = errors.SubCategory || {}
    errors.subCategory.subSubCategory = errors.SubCategory.subSubCategory || {}
    errors.subCategory.subSubCategory.fieldWithError = 'Error Message'
}
```

With lodash, I can do this:

```
const errors = {}
if(errorOnSpecificField) {
    _.set(errors, 'subCategory.subSubCategory.fieldWithError', 'Error Message');
}
```

I am trying to avoid using a third party library. Is there a more elegant solution, especially now that es2015 has object destructuring. The inverse operation is easy:

```
  let {subCategory : {subSubCategory: {fieldWithError}}} = errors
```

What is an elegant solution to deep object assignment? Thanks!

Comment: Object.assign() ? - it overrides all properties though

Comment: As you mention, because it overrides the other properties already set, this won't work for my case

Comment: you might then look for some of the many `extend` implementations

Comment: Uh, why not just use `errors.subCategory = {subSubCategory: {fieldWithError: 'Error Message'}}`? It's the exact reverse of the destructuring.

Comment: The problem is that if I already have other subSubCategories defined, it will overwrite them

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly readable way to safely assign to the deep object:

```
(((errors||{}).subCategory||{}).subSubCategory||{}).fieldWithError = 'Error Message'
```

That doesn't *create* `errors.subCategory.subSubCategory` if it doesn't already exist, though.

Comment: This actually doesn't work for assignment. For accessing, yes, but not for creating properties.

Comment: Hmm... It won't create `errors.subCategory.subSubCategory`, but it will safely assign to it if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no there is no clean way of doing this without writing a method for it (tbh you could just use the method from lodash without importing the whole library)

... however ...

**WARNING** This is for fun only. Do not try this in production (req es6).

```
Object.prototype.chainSet = function() {
  let handler = {
    get (target, name) {
      if (!(name in target)) {
        target[name] = new Proxy({}, handler)
      }
      return target[name]
    }
  }

  return new Proxy(this, handler)
}
```

use:

```
let a = {}
a.chainSet().foo.bar.baz = 1
a.foo.bar.baz // => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign() will work just fine for what you're asking.

```
let errors = { otherField: "value" };
let newobj = {subCategory : {subSubCategory: {fieldWithError: "Error goes here"}}};
Object.assign(errors, newobj);
```

This yields:

```
{
  otherField:'value',
  subCategory: {
    subSubCategory: {
      fieldWithError:'Error goes here'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if `errors = {subCategory: {x: "y"}}` and you assign `newobj`, then property `x` gets "removed" (the whole `subCategory` object is swapped out). OP is looking for a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below:

```
function ErrorRegistry(obj)
{
    this.errors = obj || {};
    this.addError = function(k, msg)
    {
        var keys = k.split('.');
        var o = this.errors;
        for(var i = 0, l = keys.length, last = l-1; i<l; i++)
        {
            if(typeof o[keys[i]] === 'undefined')
                o[keys[i]] = {};
            if(i == last)
                o[keys[i]] = msg;
            else
                o = o[keys[i]];
        }
    };
}
var errors = {'subCategory1':{'fieldWithError1':'Error1'}};
var errorRegistry = new ErrorRegistry(errors);
errorRegistry.addError('subCategory1.fieldWithError2', "Error2");
errorRegistry.addError('subCategory1.subSubCategory1.fieldWithError3', "Error3");
errorRegistry.addError('subCategory1.subSubCategory2.fieldWithError4', "Error4");
errors = errorRegistry.errors;
console.log(errors);
```